# display name based on dropdown selection in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

> Blockquote
>   I have following item in output part, in need to display last item RMC only when i select the RMC from Select a Grade:option from drop dwon list.so how to make the condition which will display only RMC when rmc select from drop down and other item will be display based on other selection.

```js
var app = angular.module('Calc', []);
app.controller('Calc_Ctrl', function ($scope) {
     /* Start constants declaration*/
     $scope.wastage_percentage = {percent : "0.05"}
     /*End constants declaration*/
//     ecah coff is different based on grade selection,so all constant cofficent is decleared inside as concreatecoeff.CoffName inside grade dropdown list
     $scope.type = {
          "Rectangular Footing" : {M20:  "M20 (1:1.5:3)", M25 : "M25 (1:1:2)", RMC : "RMC",
               M20:{
                    "concreatecoeff" : {cement : "0.03", sand : "0.01", mm_aggregate20 : "0.02", mm_aggregate12 : "0.01"},
                   
               },
           M25:{
                     "concreatecoeff" : {cement : "0.35", sand : "0.01", mm_aggregate20 : "0.02", mm_aggregate12 : "0.01"},
                    
               },
          RMC:{
                     "concreatecoeff" : { rmc : "1.05"},
                    
               }},
          "Roof Beam/Plinth Beam" : {M20:  "M20 (1:1.5:3)", RMC : "RMC",
               M20:{
                     "concreatecoeff" : {cement : "0.03", sand : "0.01", mm_aggregate20 : "0.02", mm_aggregate12 : "0.01"},
                    
               },
          RMC:{
                     "concreatecoeff" : { rmc : "1.05"},
                    
               }},
          "Rectangular / Square cloumns" : {M20:  "M20 (1:1.5:3)", RMC : "RMC",
               M20:{
                     "concreatecoeff" : {cement : "0.03", sand : "0.01", mm_aggregate20 : "0.02", mm_aggregate12 : "0.01"},
                    
               },
          RMC:{
                      "concreatecoeff" : { rmc : "1.05"},
                    
               }},
          "Round/circular columns" : {M20:  "M20 (1:1.5:3)",
               M20:{
                     "concreatecoeff" : {cement : "0.03", sand : "0.01", mm_aggregate20 : "0.02", mm_aggregate12 : "0.01"},
                    
               }},
          "Roof Slab" : {M20:  "M20 (1:1.5:3)", RMC : "RMC",
               M20:{
                    "concreatecoeff" : {cement : "0.03", sand : "0.01", mm_aggregate20 : "0.02", mm_aggregate12 : "0.01"},
                    
               },
          RMC:{
                     "concreatecoeff" : { rmc : "1.05"},
                    
               }},
             
     };

     /*Start user input values and Function to add/remove input fields*/
     $scope.choices = [{id : 'choice1', nf : 0,l2 : 0, b2 : 0, t2 : 0
          }];

     $scope.addNewChoice = function () {
          var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
          $scope.choices.push({
               'id' : 'choice' + newItemNo
          });
     };

     $scope.removeChoice = function () {
          var lastItem = $scope.choices.length - 1;
          $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
     };

     $scope.sum = function () {
          var sum = 0;
          angular.forEach($scope.choices, function (choice) {
               sum += choice.nf * choice.l2 * choice.b2 *choice.t2;
          });
          return sum;
     }
     /*End user input values and Function to add/remove input fields*/

     /*Start function to select units*/
     $scope.change = function () {
          if ($scope.data.previousSel != $scope.data.selectedOption) {
               if ($scope.data.selectedOption.name == 'feet') {
                    var feets = $scope.data.previousSel.id * $scope.data.selectedOption.id;
                    angular.forEach($scope.choices, function (choice) {
                         choice.l2 = feets * choice.l2;
                         choice.b2 = feets * choice.b2;
                         choice.t2 = feets * choice.t2;
                         choice.nf = feets * choice.nf;
                    });
               }
               if ($scope.data.selectedOption.name == 'mtrs') {
                    var mtrs = $scope.data.previousSel.id / $scope.data.selectedOption.id;
                    angular.forEach($scope.choices, function (choice) {
                         choice.l2 = choice.l2 / mtrs;
                         choice.b2 = choice.b2 / mtrs;
                         choice.t2 = choice.t2 / mtrs;
                         choice.nf = choice.nf / mtrs;
                    });
               }

               $scope.data.previousSel = $scope.data.selectedOption;
          }
     };
     $scope.data = {
          availableOptions : [{
                    id : '1',
                    name : 'mtrs'
               }, {
                    id : '3.28',
                    name : 'feet'
               }],
          previousSel : {
               id : '1',
               name : 'mtrs'
          },
          selectedOption : {
               id : '1',
               name : 'mtrs'
          } //This sets the default value of the select in the ui

     };
     /*End function to select units*/
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="concreate_rcc.js"></script>
     <body>
          <fieldset>
               <div ng-app="Calc" ng-controller="Calc_Ctrl">
                    <!--Start Input calculation-->
                    <br> <b>Input</b><br>
                    <p>Select a unit:</p>
                    <select ng-change="change()" ng-model="data.selectedOption" ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id">
                    </select>
                    <p>Select a pattern:</p>
                    <select ng-model="selectedpattern" ng-options="x for (x, y) in type" >
                    </select>
                    <p>Select a Grade:</p>
                    <select ng-model="selectedgrade" ng-options="x for (x, y) in selectedpattern">
                    </select>

                    <p>Enter the  Details</p>

                    <form data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
                         <br>  {{$index + 1}} :
                         NO of types:<input type="number" ng-model="choice.nt" />
                         NO of footings:<input type="number" ng-model="choice.nf" /><br><br>
                         Length:<input type="number" ng-model="choice.l2" />
                         width: <input type="number" ng-model="choice.b2" /><br><br>
                         Thickness: <input type="number" ng-model="choice.t2" />
                         Quantity:<input id="area" type="number" placeholder="Area" value="{{ choice.nf * choice.l2 * choice.b2 * choice.t2}}" />
                         <button ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
                         <button  ng-click="addNewChoice()">+</button>
                    </form><br><br>
                    
                    Total Quantity : {{ sum() | number:2}}
<!--                    process part:
                    grade test:  {{selectedgrade.concreatecoeff.cement}}
                    wastage_percentage: {{sum() * wastage_percentage.percent}}
                    RCC qty:{{sum() * wastage_percentage.percent + sum()}}-->

                    <br><br> <b>output</b>
                    cement:{{((sum() * wastage_percentage.percent + sum()) * (selectedgrade.concreatecoeff.cement)) | number:2}}<br>
                    sand:{{((sum() * wastage_percentage.percent + sum()) * (selectedgrade.concreatecoeff.sand))| number:2}}<br>
                    20mm aggregate:{{((sum() * wastage_percentage.percent + sum()) * (selectedgrade.concreatecoeff.mm_aggregate20))| number:2}}<br>
                    12mm aggregate:{{((sum() * wastage_percentage.percent + sum()) * (selectedgrade.concreatecoeff.mm_aggregate12))| number:2}}<br>
                    <!-- for rmc only,need to give condition:-->
                    RMC:{{((sum() * wastage_percentage.percent + sum()) * (selectedgrade.concreatecoeff.rmc))| number:2}}
                    <!--End output calculation-->
                    </fieldset>

                    </body>
                    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about to just wrapped your RMC displaying by this :

```
<div ng-if="selectedgrade=='RMC'">[display of RMC]</div>
```

ng-if is preferable to ng-show in case you would meet undefined values when it's not RMC selected, it will spam your console for nothing.